# Flex/Bison: Error recovery destructors?

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer

I have the following grammar for a comma-separated list with at least one item:

```
column_expression_list:
    column_expression {
        $$ = LinkedList_New();
        LinkedListItem *item = LinkedListItem_New($1);
        LinkedList_add($$, item);
    }
    |
    column_expression_list T_COMMA column_expression {
        LinkedListItem *item = LinkedListItem_New($3);
        LinkedList_add($1, item);
    }
;
```

But consider this:

```
column_expression error
```

The `$$ = LinkedList_New();` will leak. Is there a way I can set a destructor function for when this is popped of the stack?

Comment: Since this has nothing to do w/ the UI Framework Flex I removed that tag and added gnu-Flex [for the lexical analyzer]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing you destroy a list with all items in it using a function called "LinkedList_Del", use Bison's %destructor directive which is made especially for cleaning up allocated elements that end up not used because of error:

```
%destructor { LinkedList_Del($$); } column_expression
```

Good luck!

Reference:
http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Destructor-Decl

Comment: I swear I tried this before an just got syntax errors. Interestingly when I use `column_expression` it makes no difference - but if I use `column_expression_list` it works perfectly. Thanks so much!

Comment: oh yes, you're right, it is `column_expression_list`, since bison takes the highest level entity that can be formed, in this case `column_expression` made sense in `column_expression_list`, so the value was transferred up then `column_expression_list` is supposed to be discarded as didn't fit in a higher level type